# Why are C++ 20 range algorithms in <algorithm> and views in <ranges>?

Tags: c++, c++20

I admit this is nitpicking about naming but beside my nitpicking about naming I have a bit of a real life code review experience where I have seen people include `<ranges>` when they only need `<algorithm>` e.g. when using `std::ranges::count_if`.

So why put range algorithms in `<algorithm>` and views in `<ranges>`?
It would make more sense to me to either:

- put range algorithms in `<algorithm>` and rename `<ranges>` to `<views>`/`<range_views>`
- put both range algorithm and views in `<ranges>`

note: I know I am oversimplifying the distinction between headers, `<ranges>` also contains a lot of [concepts and building blocks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ranges), so it is possible that is part of the justification.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Views aren't algorithms, so why should they be in the algorithms header? Range algorithms *are* algorithms, so why shouldn't they be in the algorithms header?

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I never said to put views in algorithm header, possibly I typed something wrong but when rereading I can not find it...

Answer (score 3):

I am not the author of the proposals, so I cannot canonically answer why the choice was made. At best, I can suggest reasons why the choice makes sense.

The One Ranges Proposal P0896R4 doesn't seem to have rationale for the choice. Range Adaptors and Utilities P0789R3 did not have these algorithms.

> So why put range **algorithms** in `<algorithm>`

The clue is in the name :) They are algorithms, and algorithms can be found in this header.

If someone is looking for `find_if`, they can find both the iterator algorithm and the range algorithm in the same place.

> So why put range [...] views in `<ranges>`?

There used to not be views in any of the existing headers, so using the existing ones might not have been appropriate. Hence a new header was introduced.

There was an analogue for subset of views, namely range adaptor views. There were (and still are) iterator adaptors. Those are defined in `<iterator>`. I don't think that would have been a good place to put range adaptors.

> put range algorithms in `<algorithm>` and rename  to `<views>`/`<range_views>`

But `<ranges>` contains more than just views. It contains concepts such as `ranges::range`, range primitive classes such as `ranges::sentinel_t`, range specific iterators such as `ranges::borrowed_iterator_t`, functions that are analogous to iterator facilities such as `std::ranges::begin`. Naming the header `<views>` might have been misleading.

> put both range algorithm and views in `<ranges>`

Perhaps if the iterator algorithms had originally been placed in `<iterator>`, then range algorithms would have been placed in `<ranges>` to follow that convention. But as it is, the previous convention was to split the algorithms into a separate header, and that convention was followed with ranges.